# llvmpy on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: python, enthought, llvm-3.0

I'm trying to install llvmpy on ubuntu 12.04 using edpFree 7.3-2

```
# uname -a 
Linux svnserver 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

After the pip command I receive an error:

```
#./pip install llvmpy
Downloading/unpacking llvmpy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package llvmpy
    LLVM version = u'3.0'
    Generate intrinsic IDs
    Searching shared library libLLVM-3.0 in /usr/lib/llvm-3.0/lib
    Using PTX
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build/llvmpy/setup.py", line 136, in <module>
        + extra_components)
      File "/tmp/pip-build/llvmpy/setup.py", line 41, in get_libs_and_objs
        parts = run_llvm_config(['--libs'] + components).split()
      File "/tmp/pip-build/llvmpy/setup.py", line 34, in run_llvm_config
        raise Exception("%r stderr is:\n%s" % (args, stderr.decode()))
    Exception: ['llvm-config', '--libs', 'core', 'analysis', 'scalaropts', 'executionengine', 'jit', 'native', 'interpreter', 'bitreader', 'bitwriter', 'instrumentation', 'ipa', 'ipo', 'transformutils', 'asmparser', 'linker', 'support', 'vectorize', 'ptxdesc', 'ptxcodegen', 'ptxasmprinter', 'ptxinfo', 'ptx'] stderr is:
    llvm-config: unknown component name: vectorize

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    LLVM version = u'3.0'

Generate intrinsic IDs

Searching shared library libLLVM-3.0 in /usr/lib/llvm-3.0/lib

Using PTX

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build/llvmpy/setup.py", line 136, in <module>

    + extra_components)

  File "/tmp/pip-build/llvmpy/setup.py", line 41, in get_libs_and_objs

    parts = run_llvm_config(['--libs'] + components).split()

  File "/tmp/pip-build/llvmpy/setup.py", line 34, in run_llvm_config

    raise Exception("%r stderr is:\n%s" % (args, stderr.decode()))

Exception: ['llvm-config', '--libs', 'core', 'analysis', 'scalaropts', 'executionengine', 'jit', 'native', 'interpreter', 'bitreader', 'bitwriter', 'instrumentation', 'ipa', 'ipo', 'transformutils', 'asmparser', 'linker', 'support', 'vectorize', 'ptxdesc', 'ptxcodegen', 'ptxasmprinter', 'ptxinfo', 'ptx'] stderr is:

llvm-config: unknown component name: vectorize
```

The problem is on vectorize component !

As prerequisite I installed (using aptitude):

```
llvm-3.0
llvm-3.0-dev
llvm-3.0-runtime
libllvm3.0
```

May be the 3.0 must be replaced with 3.1 ?

Can You help me ?

Comment: did you tried this?
    sudo apt-get install python-llvm

Comment: no because I'm installing llvmpy under epdFree (Enthougth distribution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want at least `llvm-3.1` which has the component that is declared as missing:

```
$ llvm-config --libs vectorize
-lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
$ llvm-config --version
3.1
```

Though I would consider 3.3 if possible, as that's where development on that appears to have [reached a reasonable point](http://blog.llvm.org/2012/12/new-loop-vectorizer.html).

**Edit**: Looks like `llvmpy-0.11.0` is being pulled in which expects `llvm-3.2`. Use:

```
pip install -I llvmpy==0.10.0
```

instead to get the version that binds against `llvm-3.1`. Tested on:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal
```

Comment: Thanks very much, llvm3.1 resolve the problem with vectorize component. But now compilation stops do to error `llvmpy/include/llvm_binding/extra.h:19:28: fatal error:llvm/IRBuilder.h: No such file or directory`

`compilation terminated.`

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`
But on my pc IRbuilder.h is present `find /usr -name IRBuilder.h` 
`/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include/llvm/Support/IRBuilder.h`

Comment: Resolved IRBuilder.h I created a link `IRBuilder.h -> ./Support/IRBuilder.h`. But now a new problem on 'llvmpy/api.cpp:22:29: fatal error: llvm/DataLayout.h: No such file or directory' on my pc I don't find DataLayout.h !!!

Comment: My target is to install numba inside Edpfree 7.3-2

Comment: Resolved DataLayout.h I created a link `DataLayout.h -> ./Target/TargetData.h`. But now a new problem  `llvm/TargetTransformInfo.h: No such file or directory`. I tried to download the source file and install with python setup.py install but it's the same !!! I'm having a nightmare !

Comment: @msalese It looks like there's a bindings->llvm version mismatch issue. Please see my edit in the answer.

Comment: `/opt/edpFree-7.3-2/bin/pip install -I llvmpy==0.10.0`, give me the same error `llvmpy/api.cpp:34:38: fatal error: llvm/TargetTransformInfo.h: No such file or directory`. I could consider to install Anaconda CE [link]http://continuum.io/anacondace.html

Comment: @msalese Is there any way to reproduce with a clean environment? I had no issue when I attempted it. You're sure you have llvm-3.1 installed?

Comment: That one are installed :`# dpkg -l|grep llvm
ii  libllvm3.1                      3.1-2ubuntu1~12.04           Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
ii  llvm-3.1                        3.1-2ubuntu1~12.04           Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM)
ii  llvm-3.1-dev                    3.1-2ubuntu1~12.04           Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), libraries and headers
ii  llvm-3.1-runtime                3.1-2ubuntu1~12.04           Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), bytecode interpreter`

Comment: It seems that a lot of llvm headers file are moved in other directories or renamed. I'm checking api.cpp and I can see the include directive that search for some .h file that are not in `/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include/llvm`. As wrote upon I  found IRBuilder.h in ./Support and linked `DataLayout.h -> ./Target/TargetData.h`